# Outputting Shopify product metafields as HTML

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm working on a custom code block for the Tapcart app version of my e-commerce site on Shopify. They have the ability to add HTML, CSS and/or JS in a custom code block.
However, I cannot get the html to output the custom fragrance notes (my custom metafield) for the product. Matter of fact, I can't get anything to output-  it's just blank.

Thoughts? Appreciate your help!

```
{{product.metafields.custom.fragrance_notes}}
```

[image: tapcart custom code block editor]

I tried {{product.metafields.custom.fragrance_notes}} expecting it to output the plain text multi-line of each individual product's fragrance notes (which I have as a custom metafield for each product) but instead nothing displays at all.

Answer (score 2):

When asking for metafield data you can often meet with success by asking for the value stored at that key.

```
{{product.metafields.custom.fragrance_notes.value}}
```

Since the namespace is custom, the key is **fragrence_notes** and what you want to use or display is the **value**. So it is a key:value thing.

Of course, if your metafield is empty, you won't see anything no matter what.